# Spring webflux Security - Disable csrf with property

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have a Spring WebFlux security as follows and would like to control CSRF using property. How can I add if check for the CSRF alone here?

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securitygWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http.authorizeExchange().matchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
        //.pathMatchers("/register", "/login").permitAll()
        .anyExchange().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin()
        .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository())
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedHandler(new HttpStatusServerAccessDeniedHandler(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST))
        .and().csrf().disable()
        .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just add something like:

```
// All your stuff up here then

if(!csrfEnabled) {
    http.csrf().disable();
}

return http.build();
```